# Correct way to install Mono Framework in OS X

Tags: macos, mono, installation, uninstallation

Is there a correct way to install a new version of Mono (for example 2.10.5) having an older version already installed (for example 2.10.4)?

Which way is it possible to follow?

1. Uninstall the older version and then install the new one
2. Overwrite the older version with the new one

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just install and don't worry about it. Frameworks support multiple versions. You'll wind up with both versions available.

If you definitely want to get rid of the old version(s), then just remove the entire Mono.framework folder from /Library/Frameworks before installing the new version.

Comment: Do you know how it is possible to select among different Mono versions? For example, if I have two different versions of Mono (suppose 2.10.4 and 2.10.5), how is it possible to run 2.10.4 instead of 2.10.5. Default starts with the most recent one. In fact, if I run "mono -V" in the terminal, the currently available version is 2.10.5. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Frameworks are just organizational, executables are still found along the PATH as usual. To get a specific one, you can give the full path.

Answer (score 1):

If it is installed the same way as on Linux (configure, make, make install), you can surely overwrite it - just use the same prefix :)